# Connect Squirrel to Azure HBase cluster

Tags: azure, dns, hbase, vpn, squirrel-sql

My objective is to access my Hbase cluster on Azure with Squirrel with a Phoenix driver running on my local computer.

My Hbase cluster on Azure is operational. I can see it in the Ambari dashboard and I can access it using SSH. I can start Phoenix with the sqlline.py command pointing to one of the zookeeper nodes. The !tables command returs four lines.

My Hbase cluster is included in an Azure VNet. From my local computer (running Windows 10) I can connect to this VNet. I can ping the IP address (10.254.x.x) of the zookeeper node successfully but pinging the FQDN of the zookeeper node results in an error message:

> "Ping request could not find host zk1-.......ax.internal.cloudapp.net.
>   Please check the name and try again."

When I start Squirrel on my local computer with the URL pointing to the FQDN of the zookeeper node  I get an error message:

> "Unexpected Error occurred attempting to open an SQL connection". The
>   stack trace points to a java.util.concurrent.RuntimeException: "Unable
>   to  establish connection"

When I start Squirrel on my local computer with the URL pointing to the IP address of the zookeeper node I get a different error:

> "Unexpected Error occurred attempting to open an SQL connection". The
>   stack trace points to a java.util.concurrent.TimeoutException.

I suspect this has something to do with the Domain Name resolution problem as described here [https://superuser.com/questions/966832/windows-10-dns-resolution-via-vpn-connection-not-working]. I applied the resolution as described by LikeARock47 on Feb 23. This did not improve the situation however.

Does this indeed have to do with the Domain Name resolution issue or is the problem somewhere else?

Is there a better solution to the Domain Name resolution issue?

Answer (score 0):

A JDBC connection from Squirrel on my local Windows10 computer has succesfully been established to the Hbase cluster by using the zookeeper IP address **and the port and "/hbase-unsecure"**:

> jdbc:phoenix:10.254.x.x:2181:/hbase-unsecure

I can manage my HBase cluster with a local Squirrel now!

I'd still be interested to find out how I can get the zookeeper FQDN resolved locally.....